# how to design custom data view in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

just nondrying if I can achieve same look as this word table in asp.net. I know about gridView but I really want a controller to give me more flexibility when view the data from SQL server 
just I want some advice in how to design same look 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I looked and all advises are fever to you ajax. i know you can create custom data view but I couldn't find the blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ListView with an itemtemplate. Then you can simply create it as an HTML table.

[ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use some css, maybe use [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and modify default styles. You may find some hints how to implement that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177335/Refreshing-content-of-the-table-using-AJAX-in-ASP). You can create your own asp.net control or just go with ajax web service